# Input textbox validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I need only allow alphanumeric and space in my text box, also on paste allow alphanumeric and space.

if enter on paste **"/stackoverflow.com/#="**  I need  **stackoverflow.com**

Any simple solution, or online example?

This is example work onKeyPress

```
function isNumAlp(event) {
    var theEvent = event || window.event;
    var rv = true;
    var key = (typeof theEvent.which === 'undefined') ? theEvent.keyCode : theEvent.which;
    if (key && (key !== 8)) {
        var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
        var keycheck = /[.a-zA-Z0-9, ]/;
        if (!keycheck.test(keychar)) {
            rv = theEvent.returnValue = false; //for IE
            if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault(); //Firefox
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: @ThomasRollet I need that for my input form, I don't need special character.

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: @ThomasRollet I have only form with several text box  <input type="text" id="txtPropertyPrice" name="txtPropertyPrice"/>

Comment: @ThomasRollet I'm add example above onKeyPress, but any solution for onPaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple regular expression should do the work

```
return str.replace(/[^\w\., ]/g, '');
```

Edit: To catch `keyUp` and `paste` events at once, listen for the `input` event.

Comment: how use this regular expression?